# sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pam

Unable to execute shell script, receiving the errors

The shell script I wrote connects to remote server over ssh and executes commands.

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error
```

The User with which I'm establishing ssh connection has sudo privileges on the remote server but the user account is not defined locally within the system.

While I may have overcome the first error by using "sudo -S" within the script the second error persists

Comment: You need to create an MVCE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's a authentication error that I guess due to your user is not sudo user. YOu need to check that your user/group are allowed to use sudo.